# How to write a JPA query to ignore NULL parameters?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am executing the below query in my SpringBoot Application but getting unexpected results.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
        value = "select * from record where (?1 IS null OR LOWER(title) like %?1%) AND (?2 IS null OR LOWER(record.type) like %?2%) AND (?3 IS null OR LOWER(category) like %?3%)" )
    List<Record> getRecordsByParams(String key, String type, String category);
```

Say if my database is something like :

[image]

Now if I search for say:

`title= file,type=book, category = null;`

I'm expecting the query to work and return records with id = 1 and id = 3, but instead I'm getting an empty list.

Comment: why it has `nativeQuery=true` is its a jpql? shouldn't you omit this flag?

Comment: does it work if you provide `chemistry` or `%` as  the third parameter? Can you provide the SQL that gets actually executed, including the bind parameters used?

Comment: Are you getting any SQL Error in console. Please paste what error you getting in SpringBoot console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. This will work.
I have replaced ?1,?2,?3 to :variable_name

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from record where (:key IS null OR LOWER(title) like %:key%) AND (:type IS null OR LOWER(record.type) like %:type%) AND (:category IS null OR LOWER(category) like %:category%)")
List<Record> getRecordsByParams(String key, String type, String category);
```